# @synthesize not showing up for the auto generated properties in Xcode 4.5

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, synthesize

I am having Xcode 4.5. I have observed a very strange behavior.In previous versions of Xcode 
whenever **I control drag the outlets from the nib to .h files**, it used to **generate getters and setters** automatically and  `@synthesize` property clearly shows up in .m file . However if I do the **same thing in Xcode 4.5** , `@synthesize` **property doesn't show up**. As a result , when I try to run my project created using Xcode 4.5 in Xcode 4.3 or less, it shows the error. When I manually write @synthesize , it works perfectly fine . Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Nikolai Ruhe : I didn't down vote, instead I up voted your answer

Comment: oh ok .. I didn't observe it . I was speaking about your answer. About my question , even I want to ask the same . There is nothing wrong in that to be down voted I feel.

Comment: I don't know either, I gave up vote. I can see there is 1 downvote on your question.... oh well. Oh maybe because you spelt XCode with a capital C? I always edit to make it correct Xcode.

Comment: oh ok . that may be the reason . I have corrected it now anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You no longer need to `@synthesize` properties, this is added during compile time to your code by the compiler.

This is a new feature in the latest improvements of the compiler by Apple.

You can `@synthesize` if you want, it will just take that bit longer and have extra lines of code. By default a property named `myProperty`, will have automatically an iVar named `_myProperty`.

Answer (score 2):

Xcode 4.5 contains a newer version of clang, the compiler, that is capable of automatically synthesizing properties. So your observation is expected behavior. If you want to add the `@synthesize` directives you have to do this manually or use an older version of Xcode.

Comment: ok . Thanks a lot .I am doing it manually now coz some times got to work with older versions as well.